# Azure AD authentication with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to do performance testing of my site which uses the Azure AD authentication. In order to login to the site 3 requests are called.
in first request the clientid is passed
in the second request in the URL it is creating one parameter 'tx' and it has some value. Rest it creates the csrf token which I am extracting successfully. 
But I am facing problem in extracting the value of 'tx' 
I am checking the value in the previous requests response but I am not able to find it. Is there anything that I am missing? I checked it on Fidler too somehow I am not getting the value of the tx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you perform the login action in Chrome (say) with Developer Tools > Network open - and on the second request (sending 'tx') get the value that is sent by the browser, then search for that value in the previous response - and find how that is represented as parameters in the downloaded data.

I had a similar requirement and ended up Writing PostProcessor (to extract a value and save in a variable) and PreProcessor (to inject the variable value into the posted parameter) - you may need to process HTML, javascript or embedded JSON in the initial response.

The fact is that (more-and-more) Web Applications are embedding functionality in client-side javascript and you need to set JMeter up to emulate this.

Comment: @Dazed- Hi.. Thank you for your reply. I did try with that but somehow I am not able to fetch that value from the previous request response. The token (tx) is created when that request is called and sent as a query parameter. There is another csrf token which I am extracting by adding the post processor to further requests. But I am facing problem with (tx).

Comment: Then you may need to dig into the Azure AD Protocols (via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-protocols) and/or post the question under Azure AD, Authentication tag(s) - I think this is more about Azure than JMeter

Comment: Alternatively you could look at Java OpenSource library (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java) and wrap that into a Sampler (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html)

Comment: Hi. I got the solution. As you said I was missing something. I searched for the tx token in the previous request response and I got that in the response. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Bit of housekeeping then - you could mark this as answer ;o)